# Laravel 5.2 can't be installed with composer with php 5.5.9

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to set up a Laravel project on the server with php 5.5.9.

I've specially remembered to use Laravel 5.2 and only packages that support php 5.5, but I'm still getting errors, although Laravel itself says everything should be fine:

[image]

Any idea why is this `doctrine/annotations` suddenly asking for php 5.6?

*Edit:* This is my current composer.json file:

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.5.9",
    "laravel/framework": "5.2.*",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.2"
},
"require-dev": {
    "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
    "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0",
    "symfony/css-selector": "2.8.*|3.0.*",
    "symfony/dom-crawler": "2.8.*|3.0.*"
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `composer update` first and then install laravel.
I think this guy explains it very well [copmposer update vs composer install](https://adamcod.es/2013/03/07/composer-install-vs-composer-update.html)

Comment: Yes, thank you. This is what i ended up doing + I needed to add `--no-dev`, beacuse the basic update still gave me those errors.

Answer (score 0):

Create Your laravel project using

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel Project_name "5.2.*"
```

Answer (score 0):

I also found that for some versions of Laravel, the doctrine and guzzlehttp dependencies are messed up. You need to install PHP 5.6 for this version of doctrine or test if 6.2 would work, for example

```
"guzzlehttp/guzzle": ">=6.2"
```

instead of

```
"guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.2"
```

(I got it working with PHP7, if you have no specific needs regarding the version, you could try that, too.)